# Не парсится корректно сайт

Tags: python, парсер

Почему парсится только первая страница?

```
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh;'
                         ' Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                         'Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
URL = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730&q='
fsb=[]
name_skins=(input('Название скина:')).replace(' ','|',1)
page=int(input('Введите страницы:'))
URL= f'{URL}{name_skins}'
for i in range(1,page+1):
    URL= f'{URL}#p{i}_price_asc'
    print(URL)
    r=requests.get(URL,headers)
    soup = BS(r.text,'lxml')
    quotes = soup.find_all('div', class_='market_listing_row market_recent_listing_row market_listing_searchresult')
    for quote in quotes:
        fsb.append(quote)
        print(','.join(quote.text.split()))
    URL= f'https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730&q={name_skins}'
```

Comment: Потому что всё, что стоит после символа `#`, не считается частью URL (с точки зрения протокола HTTP) и обрабатывается скриптами внутри браузера, то есть таким способом вы не сможете получить остальные страницы

Comment: Каким образом я смогу обойти это, не подскажете?

Comment: может стоит воспользоваться библиотеками [steam_community_market](https://pypi.org/project/steam-community-market/) или [steampy](https://github.com/bukson/steampy) ?